# What is the pronunciation of English word "feeling" in General American accent? The normal sound [ˈfilɪŋ] or add the "l" sound, [ˈfiɫ lɪŋ]?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, accent, american-english

What is the pronunciation of English word *feeling* in General American accent? The normal sound [ˈfilɪŋ] or double the "l" sound, [ˈfiɫ lɪŋ] ?

Comment: Related ELU question: [L in the middle of a word: dark l or light l?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282122)

Answer (score 4):

The thing you call "double l" is more generally known as "dark l", and this topic has been researched (inconclusively) for decades. The classic study of the question is [Sproat & Fujimura](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/dm/featgeom/sproat-fujimura93-L.pdf) 1993 "Allophonic variation in English /l/ 
and  its  implications  for  phonetic  implementation". One problem is that there isn't a well-defined and obvious boundary between dark and clear instances of /l/. It is now understood that there is a continuum of "darkness" realizations, dependent on context. The context for "fee**l**ing" is more on the "light l" side, although bear in mind that this is derived from "fee**l**" which is on the dark side of "l". [This paper](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~jiahong/publications/c06.pdf) by Yuan & Liberman proposes a way of quantifying darkness, but does not address the specific word or similar words.

Phonological considerations favor a "short" interpretation of /l/, in case you are hoping to look at duration and not darkness. A single intervocalic consonant phoneme immediately after a stressed lax vowel tends to get lengthened a bit, the rationale often being that stressed syllables in English cannot be just CV. This predicts a difference between "feeling" [fɪjlɪŋ] versus "filling" [fɪlˑɪŋ]. Consonant duration is not categorial in English, so as with darkness, the choice is not between "short" and "long", it is a continuum ranging from "shorter" to "longer".

Answer (score 0):

I would say it [ˈfiː.lɪŋ]. (Source: native GA speaker.)

However, there's considerable variation within GA, and the only way to really be sure would be to record a lot of people saying the word several times, then look at the length of the [l] in the spectrograms, and compare it to the length of a reference "short" [l] in another word.